# Custom onDraw() method not called

Tags: android, drawing

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/svLL" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!--
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/scrollbar_2_text" />
        -->
        <com.mypackage.MyDrawableView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public class MyDrawableView extends View {

    Context thisContext;

    public MyDrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context);
        thisContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setTextSize(12);
        canvas.drawText("Blah blah", 0, 100, paint);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    // Your member variable declaration here
    // Called when the activity is first created.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Your code here super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xmllayout);
        LinearLayout svll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.svLL);
        svll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300));
    }

}
```

I am putting a breakpoint, but breakpoint is never hit inside `onDraw()` method, what's wrong ?

Comment: What is the code of your Activity? maybe the issue is there?

Comment: public class MyActivity extends Activity {

 // Your member variable declaration here

 // Called when the activity is first created.
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Your code here
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.xmllayout);
  LinearLayout svll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.svLL);
  svll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300));
 }
}

Comment: I moved your code into the question, so it's more understandable

Comment: thanks klez, no body catched the error yet, must be some simple mistake :(

Comment: interesting, i overrode onLayout and onMeasure. breakpoint was hit in these functions. but for onLayout the bottom is coming 0, right is 300 left and top are 0. is this the reason onDraw is not called ? is not there any customview example code using xml ?

Comment: when i made it fill_parent also same result. i tried doing it 300px and 300px in layout xml, also bottom is always coming 0 and onDraw is never called. i tend to assume that this way it is not gonna work and is faulty

Comment: have you try setWillNotDraw (false) in constructor

Comment: In my case when I set background then onDraw works otherwise not.

Answer (score 123):

Add `setWillNotDraw(false)` in MyDrawableView constructor. Original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7784369/237232).

Comment: This applies to viewgroup not view

Comment: Worked for me. But there is a problem. I'm animating the `View` that I have clipped. When `onDraw` is overridden, the view flickers (looks like it was drawn again). When unclipped, it animates smoothly. Can you help me solve this?

Answer (score 38):

Your View has a height of 0. You set your View to have `height=wrap_content`, but your don't override `onMeasure()` to tell the UI toolkit how big your View is.

Comment: In my case it Not workes, LinearLayoutCompat >> HorizontalScrollView >> LinearLayout >> CustomView . when CustomView inherited Textview it there is no problem, but it faces a problem when it extends ConstrainLayout or LinearLayout

Answer (score 18):

You need to `@Override` the `OnMeasure(int, int)` method to specify the size of your view by calling `setMeasuredDimension(int,int)`.

If you don't, the default method will set your view to have size `width=0 height=0`. And therefore don't even try to call `onDraw` at all.

The `OnMeasure` method calls `setMeasuredDimension(int,int)` which tells how big is your view.

(So you need to get the size of the android screen on the `OnMeasure` method and call `setMeasuredDimension` accordingly).

Comment: Indeed, when the dimensions are 0 then onDraw() isn't called. I was using getSuggestedMinimumWidth() which returned 0. I then used that with setMeasuredDimension() to make a square... needless to say, onDraw() wasn't called.

Answer (score 3):

Just make `layout_width` and `layout_height` of the custom view some fix at initial time instead of `wrap_content` or `fill_parent`.
That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use invalidate() in constructor method to get the onDraw Called.

Answer (score 1):

Probably

```
setMinimumHeight(width);
setMinimumWidth(height);
```

in constructor are not set or `onMeasure()` is not overriden.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more reason that your view might not be appearing. If you are creating your custom ViewGroup with subviews, remember to add the subviews to your ViewGroup.

In your ViewGroup constructor call

```
addView(mySubView);
```

Also remember to measure and layout your subviews in `onLayout()`

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    mySubview.measure(...);
    mySubview.layout(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you set the custom view width, you should set scroll width.

```
FMChart = (HKFMDrawChart)findViewById(R.id.fm_chart);
FMChart.setWidth(xxxx);
float scrollViewWidth = FMChart.getScrellViewWidth(); 
FMChart.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
      (int) (scrollViewWidth + HKApplication.getScreenWidth() / 2),
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
FMChart.postInvalidate(); // onDraw();
```

Answer (score -2):

Though I am new in android, still I believe the problem is because of

```
setContentView(R.layout.xmllayout);
```

Instead of `"R.layout.xmllayout"`, pass `MyDrawableView` object (using `findViewById`) and check.
I have not tried, but hope, it will work.