# Simple canvas drawing not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I have a custom view on top of another view in which I want to draw stuff. The canvas has `width 1080` and `height 1920` (fixed portrait orientation). I have confirmed that this view is indeed sitting on top of another view (camera preview). However, the `onDraw` function isn't drawing anything visible. When I try `canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 10, 10)` I see a blue rectangle, but when I change the position of the top left corner to something like `(100, 100)` there's nothing on the screen. `(100, 100)` is certainly within the dimensions of my screen size but why doesn't the rectangle show up?

```
public class OverlayView extends View {

    private Paint paint;

    public BarcodeOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 50, 50, paint);
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}
```

Comment: Are you using the FULL_SCREEN Layout attribute from WindowManager?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, I've added my `MainActivity.java` to the original post

Comment: I don´t know if this is the problem. But I detected the problem with the FULL_SCREEN  feature a few days ago.I am drawing some animated bitmaps on a SurfaceView and as soon as I put this feature to my activity, the animated bitmap is disapearing on certain areas and apearing again if they passed this area. I don´t know if it´s a bug, but just remove the features and try if the issue is related to it.

Comment: I'm not dynamically changing the position or the paint object. The above code just doesn't work on app startup.

Comment: I know that, I just want to explain what the cause is. If you set it to 100,100 it is not visible, so (if it´s the same problem) it could be in that area where the view is not visible.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs strange, I removed that snippet of code and it works fine

Comment: I really guess it is a bug in the system, I have no fix for it.... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call to `Canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 50, 50, paint)` will not draw anything because the passed arguments are wrong in a way that the points by which should be the desired rectangle drawn represent, lets call it a reversed rectangle.

If you look at description (JavaDoc) of `Canvas.drawRect(float, float, float, float, Paint)` method you will see that the first argument is **left**, second one is **top**, third one is **right** and the fourth one is **bottom**, that is where yours issue lies, the **right** (50) point is before **left** (100) point on X axis, and also the **bottom** (50) point is before **top** (100) point on Y axis.

So if I assume that by calling `Canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 50, 50, paint)` you would like to draw a rectangle that is **50 px** wide and **50 px** tall at **X** position of **100 px** and **Y** position of **100 px** you should be able to achieve that by calling `Canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 150, 150, paint)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your constructor:

```
setWillNotDraw(false);
```

This could be the same problem as in [Custom onDraw() method not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343912/custom-ondraw-method-not-called)

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't do anything